# Android: same menu throughout my activity

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I'm an android application and I would display in my Action Bar icon, why I use a file main.xml

I call this menu in all my view, but I would like some on some page menu item does not appear, how to do this?

My Views extends BaseMenuActivity and BaseMenuActivity extends Activity.
do I report "onOptionsItemSelected" and "onCreateOptionsMenu" throughout my views?

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_shopping_client"
    android:title="client"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_shopping_cart_buy"
    android:icon="@drawable/shopping_cart_buy"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="buy" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_shopping_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/shopping_cart"
    android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom" />
```

in my activities :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    item.setEnabled(false);
    item.setVisible(false);
    MenuItem item2= menu.findItem(R.id.action_shopping_cart_buy);
    item2.setVisible(false);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(id == R.id.action_shopping_cart_buy){
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside you BaseMenuActivity take a boolean that will be set inside the subclass.

and in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) inflate menu only based upon that boolean value.

Comment: ok but I have an item on this menu that should launch a function in the class, the item is displayed on this view (on only one view) and therefore how to call the function in the sub-class for BaseMenuActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You override this function public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}
in every sub class and which Item want to display in class.
Example :
 MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    item.setEnabled(true);

But first you declare this item.setEnabled(false); in your parent class

Comment: ok but I have an item on this menu that should launch a function in the class, the item is displayed on this view (on only one view) and therefore how to call the function in the sub-class for BaseMenuActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You Can hide Menu By doing this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
```

Replace Boolean false instead of true

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return false;

}
```